# No icons, launcher, top panel or anything else while 'Try Ubuntu'

Tags: boot, unity, boot-repair

I just got Ubuntu live media on USB and pressed 'Try Ubuntu' and that worked very well, so I decided to install. At the end of the install I got a fail message and it said something about the boot loader, and that made me unable to boot to Ubuntu.

I wanted to use the boot-repair tool, but the problem is now that, when I go to 'Try Ubuntu' I just get the background but no icons, top bar or anything like that? Only the background and my mouse. I can't open anything, but just chill with my mouse.

I tried (old Windows user) to press ctrl+alt+delete and that logged me out. It said I could log in again, but I don't really know what username to use or which password that is useful. I've been trying to reboot several times, but I just get the same result.

Is it possible for me to use the boot-repair tool in another way than with the 'Try Ubuntu' or can I fix the icon, launcher, top bar in a way (without using the Termal. Since I can't open it).

Comment: when booting the HHD (without any Ubuntu DVD or USB), do you see the GRUB menu ?

Comment: The problem is also that I don't really know how to. (feeling really stubbid right now)

Comment: I had a similar problem, you can boot into Ubnutu using GRUB. Once in, you can use the [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: The new problem is I can't get the GRUB menu. I've tried lots of different Things but nothing really Works.